# Control auto-LV-mounting

Tags: debian, lvm

On Debian, I want to control the auto-mount of LVs, because I have multiple nodes that have access to a shared VG. For example, when I try to activate a LV, I want it to refuse the activation.

I tried to use an `udev` rule but I'm not sure if this is the best way, becau  se udev is used for device naming.
I also tried to deal with intern `xen` scripts but it is not low-level enough.
Where should I write this hack ?